# ajax image upload and send variable

Tags: php, ajax, image, variables, upload

I have ajax that sends the info to the upload.php file

It all works as it should but i need to send the id along with the ajax upload data...

I tried to play around with arrays but i was not successfull.

My ajax is as follows -

```
// image transfer
// Verify server has been entered
server = document.getElementById('serverUrl').value;
if (server) {
    // Specify transfer options
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = imagefile.substr(imagefile.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    //alert (options.fileName);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    // Transfer picture to server
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imagefile, server, function(r) {
        $('#example3').hide();
        document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Image Upload successful ";
        $('#done').show();
        //})
        document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Data Upload successful ";
    }, function(error) {
        document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload Successfull" + error.code;
        ;
    }, options);
}
//image transfer end
```

And as a receiving upload.php i have the following

```
<?php

// Directory where uploaded images are saved
$dirname = "upload/"; 

// If uploading file
if ($_FILES) {
    print_r($_FILES);
    mkdir ($dirname, 0777, true); 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$dirname."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}
?>
```

Comment: There is no AJAX, you use some objects and don't provide their descriptions.

Comment: Is there a way to send a variable along with the image to the php page ?

Comment: Of course, taking, the files that you upload goes into array $_FILES[...], when variables will go into $_POST[...] or $_GET[...] arrays. And there are a lot more. It is Superglobals, red here about them http://www.nusphere.com/php/php_superglobals.htm